# Finding the horizontal asymptotes

Tags: calculus, limits

In Stewart's *Calculus* book, there is an example of finding the horizontal asymptotes for
$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2x^2 + 1}}{3x-5}$ 
And author starts solving it by writing that $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ for positive $x$, so we can write numerator as $\frac{\sqrt{2x^2 + 1}}{\sqrt{x^2}}$ 
And the same he does for negative $x$. He says that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x| = -x$.

But $\sqrt{x^2} = \pm x$ for any x, isn't it?

UPDATE: When I wrote we can write numerator, I meant that we have to divide by highest power of $x$ from denominator first, that's why $\frac{\sqrt{2x^2 + 1}}{x}$ transforms to $\frac{\sqrt{2x^2 + 1}}{\sqrt{x^2}}$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site. The $\pm$ symbol is obtained by typing `$\pm$`.

Answer (score 1):

View this as
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{3x-5}=\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{\sqrt{(3x-5)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2x^2+1}{(3x-5)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2x^2+1}{9x^2-30x+25}}
$$
Now it is clear as $x\rightarrow\infty$ the inside of the radical goes to $\frac{2}{9}$, so we find that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{3x-5}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}
$$

Comment: Okay, above is clear, and asymptote for me is clear, but what is not clear how the author interprets rule above, why √(x^2) = x for x>0? It must always be +-x  for any x, isnt it?

Comment: $\sqrt(x^2)$ is, by convention, the nonegative one of the values $x$ and $-x.$

Comment: @ChrisLeary but in second case author replaces x with -√(x^2), where did that - came from?

Comment: $3x-5 \neq \sqrt{(3x-5)^2}$ for $x < 5/3$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg but I'm talking about x, not 3x-5

Comment: @Vanconts - If $x$ is negative, which of $x$ and $-x$ is nonnegative?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by defining the absolute value of a number.

**Definition.**  Let $x$ be a real number.  Then the *absolute value* of $x$ is the distance of $x$ from $0$ on the real number line.

We can use this definition to obtain an algebraic formula for $|x|$.

Keep in mind that distances cannot be negative.  On the real number line, the distance between two numbers is the larger number minus the smaller number.

Observe that if $x \geq 0$, then the distance of $x$ from $0$ is $|x| = x - 0 = x$.  On the other hand, if $x < 0$, then the distance of $x$ from $0$ is $|x| = 0 - x = -x$.  Hence,
$$|x| = \begin{cases}
        x & \text{if $x \geq 0$}\\
        -x & \text{if $x < 0$}
        \end{cases}
$$
For instance, since $5 > 0$, $|5| = 5$.  Since $-9 < 0$, $|-9| = -(-9) = 9$.

Remember that $\sqrt{x}$ represents the principal (nonnegative) square root of $x$.  For instance, $\sqrt{5^2} = \sqrt{25} = 5$ and $\sqrt{(-9)^2} = \sqrt{81} = 9$.  If $x \geq 0$, then $\sqrt{x^2} = x$.  If $x < 0$, then $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$.  Hence,
$$|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$$

> But $\sqrt{x^2} = \pm x$ for any $x$, isn't it?

No.

If that were true, then $|5| = \pm 5$.  However, it is not true that $|x| = -5$.

We use the [$\pm$ sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus%E2%80%93minus_sign) to indicate that a symbol may be replaced by either the $+$ or $-$ sign.

Consider the problem $x^2 = 4$.  We will solve it in two ways.
\begin{align*}
x^2 & = 4\\
x^2 - 4 & = 0\\
(x + 2)(x - 2) & = 0
\end{align*}
Since a product is equal to zero if and only if one of the factors is equal to zero, $x + 2 = 0$ or $x - 2 = 0$.
\begin{align*}
x + 2 & = 0 & x - 2 & = 0\\
x & = -2 & x & = 2
\end{align*}
Direct substitution into the equation $x^2 = 4$ shows that both solutions are valid.  Therefore, we can write $x = \pm 2$.

\begin{align*}
x^2 & = 4\\
\sqrt{x^2} & = \sqrt{4}\\
|x| & = 2
\end{align*}
There are two real numbers whose distance from $0$ on the real number line is $2$.  They are $2$ and $-2$.  Hence, $x = \pm 2$.

On the other hand, if we are asked to solve $|5| = x$, there is only one solution, namely $x = 5$.  It is not true that $x = -5$.  Thus, it does not make sense to write $x = \pm 5$ in this context since we cannot substitute $-5$ for $x$ in the equation $|5| = x$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Didn't understand, what relation absolute values have to squre roots?

Comment: As I said, $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ since $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ if $x \geq 0$ and $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$ if $x < 0$.

Comment: The problem was that I did not know that $\sqrt{x}$ - is a POSITIVE root

Answer (score -1):

The function $$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$$ always gives you a positive number, in real, of course. If you’re not convince, you can plot $f(x)$ on a calculator. For any $x$, the function $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$,you get $-x$ If x is negative to start with(thus $-x$ Positive), vice versa.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).